# Will "clear_user()" for .bss clearing leads to page fault during ELF loading in function load_elf_binary?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, elf

The discussion below applies to 32-bit ARM Linux.

When kernel is loading an ELF executable file, function `load_elf_binary` will be called.

I believe it is the following code snippet that clears .bss section:

```
nbyte = ELF_PAGEOFFSET(elf_bss);
if (nbyte) {
    nbyte = ELF_MIN_ALIGN - nbyte;
        if (nbyte > elf_brk - elf_bss)
            nbyte = elf_brk - elf_bss;
                if (clear_user((void __user *)elf_bss +
                    load_bias, nbyte)) {
            /*
             * This bss-zeroing can fail if the ELF
             * file specifies odd protections. So
             * we don't check the return value
             */
        }
 }
```

However, elf_bss is user land pointer, if this pointer is referenced, I believe **a page fault would arise** because the physical page frame has not been committed yet for virtual address in that range.
But that's rather confusing that a user land page fault arises while kernel land code is being executed.

Is my interpretation right?

Comment: clear_user handles exactly that scenario. It takes care of accessing the given user space address. So the kernel should never get a fault on any user address unless there is a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So there is expected page fault for this clear_user ?

Comment: kaylum possibly didn't see your follow-up question, because you didn't address (@) him.